# Using python 3 to extract data from googlemaps api response

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

I am using the `googlemaps` library to query the google maps api.I would like to extract the name of a City based on zip code.

For example, for zip code `23325` I would like to extract `Chesapeake`.

Here is my initial code:

```
import googlemaps
from keys import google_api_key

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=google_api_key)
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('23325')
print(geocode_result)
```

Here are the results from printing the geocode_results:
`[{'address_components': [{'long_name': '23325', 'short_name': '23325', 'types': ['postal_code']}, {'long_name': 'Indian River', 'short_name': 'Indian River', 'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Chesapeake', 'short_name': 'Chesapeake', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Virginia', 'short_name': 'VA', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}], 'formatted_address': 'Chesapeake, VA 23325, USA', 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 36.8399469, 'lng': -76.21933109999999}, 'southwest': {'lat': 36.7870261, 'lng': -76.25747489999999}}, 'location': {'lat': 36.8179707, 'lng': -76.2305308}, 'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 36.8399469, 'lng': -76.21933109999999}, 'southwest': {'lat': 36.7870261, 'lng': -76.25747489999999}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJTcQMfRK9uokRcVFVU9zMizw', 'types': ['postal_code']}]`

When I look at the type
`print(type(geocode_result))`

Python tells me
`<class 'list'>`

If I try anything like `geocode_result[1]` I get the following error message:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

If I try `geocode_result['address_components']` I get a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` message

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you try `geocode_result[0]`?

Comment: I get the same results as printing geocode_results. I tried using bytes.decode ... but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of `dict`s. So you can get the first item using the list index, and then you get the dict element using a key.

So for example:

```
item = geocode_result[0]
item['address_components'] # Returns another list
item['formatted_address'] # Returns a string 'Chesapeake, VA 23325, USA'
```

Comment: Booom! If I had a kid on the way, I would name them after you! Thank you so much! I used your suggestion `item = geocode_result[0]` and then `x = item['formatted_address']` .  I then used `x2 = x.split(",")[0]` to pull out the City name.

Answer (score 0):

Thats reverse geocode. This would do the trick :

```
import urllib, json
import urllib.request
geocode = input("Enter zip code : ")
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=" + geocode
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print(data)
```